# How do I create a 2D array in python?

Tags: python

Problem:
I'm trying to create an 2D array( like the last line in the code) using a for loop like the last line in the following matlab code:

```
for i=1:NumLines
J=i-1;  J=0,1,2,...
if (mod(J,2)==0)
    %Even
    gj=gj_even;
else
    %Odd
    gj=gj_odd;
end
Erot(i)=((B0*J*(J+1))-D0*J^2*(J+1)^2)*planck*c; %correct

dnu_Stokes(i)=-B0*2*(2*J+3)+D0*(3*(2*J+3)+(2*J+3)^3); %2005
Xj_Stokes(i)=(J+1)*(J+2)/(2*J+3); %correct
dRCS_Stokes(i,:)=(112*pi^4/15).*(gj*planck*c*B0*(nu0+dnu_Stokes(i))^4*gammaSquared)./(((2*I+1).^2)*kb*T).*Xj_Stokes(i).*exp(-Erot(i)./(kb*T));
```

Heres my problem.Unlike matlab, python doesn't create a new array for you so you would have to create an empty array before you can place value insides them. I keep getting "**only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"** error .Here is my python attempt:

```
dnu_Stokes=np.array([])#empty arrays
Erot= np.array([])
Xj_Stokes=np.array([])
dRcs_Stokes=np.array([])
anti_dnu_Stokes=np.array([])
anti_Xj_Stokes=np.array([])
anti_dRcs_Stokes=np.array([]) #empty arrays

for i in range(1,NumLines):
    J= i-1
    if (J%2==0):
        gj=gj_even
    else:
        gj=gj_odd

    i_Erot = (B0*J*(J+1))-((D0*(J**2))*((J+1)**2)*planck*c)
    Erot= np.append(Erot,i_Erot) # append vaues to EROT array (WORKS)

    i_dnu_Stokes=-B0*2*(2*J+3)+D0*(3*(2*J+3)+(2*J+3)**3)
    dnu_Stokes= np.append(dnu_Stokes,i_dnu_Stokes)# append vaues to dnu_skotes array (wORKS)

    i_Xj_Stokes=(J+1)*(J+2)/(2*J+3)
    Xj_Stokes= np.append(Xj_Stokes,i_Xj_Stokes) # append vaues to XJ array (WORKS)


    dRcs_Stokes[i-1,:]=((112*((math.pi)**4))/15)*(((gj)*planck*c*B0*((nu0+i_dnu_Stokes)**4)*gammaSquared)/(((2*I+1)**2)*kb*T))*(i_Xj_Stokes*(math.exp(((-i_Erot)/(kb*T))))) ###I dont know how to append values to create a 2D array###
```

Comment: Preallocate using [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html). Appending to numpy arrays is bad. Extending the size of an array in MATLAB is also a bad, _bad_ idea because it slows down your program by orders of magnitude if there are a significant number of resize operations. MATLAB also has [`zeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, "hello world" example of what you're trying to do:

```
arr = []
for row_num in range(5):  # add 5 rows. row_num is 0...4
    row = []
    for col_num in range(6):  # add 6 columns. col_num is 0...5
        print("computing element for row:", row_num, ", col:", col_num)
        element = (row_num * col_num)  # this is where you compute each element
        row.append(element)
    arr.append(row)

arr = np.array(arr)
```

You should be able to take it from here

Comment: What does "arr = np.array(arr)" do?

Comment: @Mikal it creates a numpy array from the given array(`arr`)

Comment: The `append` function can be a very slow way to construct a large array, when memory must be reallocated and data copied, as the array grows. I would advise preallocation, if the number of elements is known ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know (or can you calculate) the dimensions of your array, or the number of entries?

You can take a 1D array of some length and use `reshape` to change its dimensions.

For instance, consider that you know ahead of time that you will store 100 values. You can preallocate an array of zeros, for example:

```
a = np.zeros(100)
```

And then reshape it any number of ways:

```
b = a.reshape(10, 10) # 10x10 2D array
c = a.reshape(2, 5, 10) # 2x5x10 3D array
```

etc.

Indexing is as you would expect:

```
print(b[0]) # array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
print(b[0][2]) # 0.0
print(c[1][3][8]) # 0.0
```

You can use indexing to set a value:

```
b[0][2] = 1.234
print(b[0]) # array([0.   , 0.   , 1.234, 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ,       0.   ])
```

Using `append` will slow your program down a lot, if you are working with a large array.

Preallocation will save time and memory, and help you catch indexing bugs.

Hopefully this helps in rethinking your problem.

Comment: So at the end of 30 iterations, "dRcs_Stokes" is suppose to be a 30x3000 array. In. other words, I am adding 3000 data values in each iteration on a new row. This where  I am confused on.

Comment: Preallocate a 90000-element array, reshape it to 30x3000, and use indexing to set a value at a position in the reshaped array.